# Could not fetch URI when Child Value is Set in Realtime Database from Firebase Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm setting a value in Firebase Realtime Database from a Firebase Function in Node.js. The Function sends a base64 image to an API and stores the data returned by the API in Realtime Database. All my service accounts are set to the Editor role. When my code tries to set the value this error shows up in the console:

```
Could not fetch URI /computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/service-accounts/default/token

at Request._callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:100:13)
at Request.self.callback (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:1044:10)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/google-auth-library/node_modules/request/request.js:965:12)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

My Node code is:

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const firebase = require('firebase');

exports.identifyUpdate = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {

    const fileBucket = object.bucket;
    const filePath = object.name;
    const contentType = object.contentType;
    const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

    if(!filePath.substring(0,filePath.indexOf('/')) == 'updates') {
        console.log("Triggered by non-update photo")
        return null;
    }

    console.log("Update photo added")

    // Create Firebase app (for Realtime Database access)

    var config = {
        apiKey: "xxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxx",
        databaseURL: "xxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxx",
    };

    if(!firebase.apps.length) {
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    // Trace back to Update stored in Realtime Database

    const database = firebase.database().ref()
    const pendingRef = database.child('pendingUpdates')

    console.log(filePath)

    const splitPath = filePath.split(path.sep)

    const patientID = splitPath[1]
    console.log('Patient ID: ' + patientID)

    const updateID = splitPath[2]
    console.log('Update ID: ' + updateID)

    const updateRef = pendingRef.child(patientID).child(updateID)

    console.log('Found Update reference')

    const photoRef = updateRef.child('photoURLs').child(fileName)

    console.log('Photo Reference: ' + photoRef)

    // Download and convert image to base64

    const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket)
    const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName)
    const metadata = {
        contentType: contentType
    };

    var base64;

    return bucket.file(filePath).download({
        destination: tempFilePath
    }).then(() => {
        console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath)
    }).then(() => {

        base64 = base64_encode(tempFilePath)
        console.log("Base 64: " + base64)

    }).then(() => {
    // Send image data to Kairos

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            uri: 'https://api.kairos.com/recognize',
            body: {
                'image': base64,
                'gallery_name': 'gallerytest1'
            },
            headers: {
                'app_id': 'xxxxx',
                'app_key': 'xxxxx'
            },
            json: true
        }

        return new Promise (() => {
            console.log(options)
            request(options)
            .then(function(repos) {

                console.log('API call succeeded');

                console.log('Kairos response: ' + repos);

                const apiResult = repos['images']
                console.log("Result \n" + JSON.stringify(apiResult))

                const faceData = face_data(apiResult)

                console.log("face data\n" + JSON.stringify(face_data(apiResult)))

                const photoURL = photoRef.once('value')
                console.log(photoURL)
                updateRef.child('faceData').set({photoURL : faceData})

            }) 
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err)
            })
        });

    })

    // Delete app instance (to prevent concurrency leaks)

    const deleteApp = () => app.delete().catch(() => null);
    deleteApp.call

})

function base64_encode(file) {
    // read binary data
    var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
    // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
    return new Buffer(bitmap).toString('base64');
}

function face_data(response) {

    var faceData = {};

    for(i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

        const face = response[i]["transaction"];
        const id = face["subject_id"]
        const topLeftX = face["topLeftX"]
        const topLeftY = face["topLeftY"]
        const width = face["width"]
        const height = face["height"]

        faceData[i] = {
            'face_id': id,
            'topLeftX': topLeftX,
            'topLeftY': topLeftY,
            'width': width,
            'height': height
        }

        console.log(faceData[i])        

    }

    return faceData

}
```

Comment: The `/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/service-accounts/default/token` URL in the error message seems to indicate that there's a problem getting a token for the default service account. If that's in Firebase, can you reproduce it without calling the 3rd party API at all? While that wouldn't solve the problem, it would help isolating it to a smaller section of code.

Comment: I tried doing that, and the error is still there. I suspect the issue is with updateRef.child('faceData').set({photoURL : faceData}) and the service account related to that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on a paid plan (Flame or Blaze)? If not you cannot call an external service from a Cloud Function.

See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ which explains that "The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services" (You have to hover on the question mark close to "Cloud Functions" title).

Comment: I'm on the Flame plan, the response from the API is coming back and printing fine. I did have an issue with the permissions for the same code for setting the database value, so I'm thinking it might be related to that.